# SQL limit to 5 records, roll up bogus values and print last

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use MySQL to print the top 5 company names and user counts in order of subscribers descending.  I also want to roll up bogus company names like 'N/A', '' (blank), 'null' and list them as Unspecified at the bottom of the results.

Here is what it should look like:

**Company   Subscribers**

Microsoft         10
Google           8
Facebook       6
Apple              2
Unspecified    9

You can see 'Unspecified' is at the bottom despite it having 9 people.

Normally I use a case statement to roll up these bogus values, like so:

```
 SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN sc.company_name not in ('null', 'n/a', '')
                    THEN company_name
                ELSE 'Unspecified'
            END as company, count(*) as subscribers
        from table
    group by company
        ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN company = 'Unspecified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, subscribers DESC, company
```

However, the above approach doesn't work when limiting to 5 records.

I've also tried using a union like so:

```
select * from
(SELECT
company_name as company, count(*) as subscribers
from table
where company_name not in ('null', 'n/a', '')
group by company
order by subscribers desc, company asc
limit 4) z
union all
select 'Unspecified' as company, count(*) as subscribers
from table
where company_name in ('null', 'n/a', '')
group by company
```

But this doesn't work because the Unspecified row is not necessarily always in the top 5.

Is this possible in a single SQL statement?  I can't use stored procedures or anything fancy because this is for a Jasper report.

Comment: So  top 4 + bogus? or Top 5 but if one is bogus go last?

Comment: Your first query is missing a `)` and also doesn't have `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Top 5 companies, and if one is 'Unspecified' then print it last.

Comment: `subs` should be `count`

Comment: @Barmar Shouldnt be `count` neither because is a reserved word.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's a keyword, not reserved.

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure? I always call those reserved words.  Like this ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845663.aspx

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html `COUNT` isn't even a keyword, it's just a built-in aggregation function.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Your link is for Access, not MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar I know. I mean in general I call `COUNT` reserved word everywhere. SQL Server say is [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) But as you show in your link, for mysql looks have a different meanning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your first query, but don't put the check for `Unspecified` in the `ORDER BY`, and limit it to the top 5. Then put that into a subquery, and reorder that to put `unspecified` last.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN sc.company_name not in ('null', 'n/a', '')
                THEN company_name
            ELSE 'Unspecified'
        END as company, count(*) as count
    from table
    group by company
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 5) AS x
ORDER BY CASE WHEN company = 'Unspecified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, count DESC, company
```